# Will holes bored for radon mitigation cause basement flooding?

Tags: basement

A company has said that they would drill a hole in the basement to get rid of radon level.

Will this cause flooding from the ground beneath the basement?

Thanks.

Phil

Comment: That is not how you abate radon as I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

No. If you have that much hydro-static pressure now, water would've already found a way in. A basement is not a boat.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a pipe is installed and then sealed, after that the pipe is taken outside, some systems have fans to power the flow outside the home with monitoring gauges to verify the system is working and not letting the possible gases in the home. If the company is just drilling a hole find someone who knows how to do it correctly.

Comment: Is the "then sealed" part the answer to the question? I'm not sure how you'd assume that all there was to the mitigation system is a hole.

Comment: Yes if there is just a hole the home would be subject to much higher levels of radon , after that I did mention the fans and monitoring system I thought it was clear but some have never had to deal with radon problems. A pipe through the slab and caped off would do nothing.

Comment: Sure, but my point was at the question is about water, not radon mitigation.

Comment: If a gas can make it in so will water.